# How to parse multiple nested JSON objects/arrays with GSON?

Tags: android, arrays, json, gson

I have been trying to wrap my head around how to parse nested objects and arrays with GSON, still stuck. How can I parse the nested items listed in the "results" array?

```
{
"item": {
    "results": [
        {
            "__metadata": {
                "url": "google.com",
                "type": "website"
            },
            "listed": true,
            "market": 225,
            "town": "Toronto"
        },
        {
            "__metadata": {
                "url": "twitter.com",
                "type": "website"
            },
            "listed": true,
            "market": 225,
            "town": "Calgary"
        }
    ]
}
}
```

How can I easily do this with GSON within Android?

Thank you!

Comment: refer this link http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_json_parser.htm

Comment: What u have tried to parse posted simple JSON String?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Android Studio

1. Download Plugin "GsonFormat"
2. Create your model class
3. Open Code->Generate->Gson
4. Paste your json click ok - if json is valid then it will convert the following json to java class (pojo)
5. Now create Gson object

   Gson gson=new Gson();
6. Convert Json to java object

   T obj = gson.fromJson(contents, tClass);
7. Now use this object "obj" to get values